# Password encryption

Tags: java, hash, passwords, compare, sha512

I encrypt password using this code

```
 public static byte[] encrypt(String password) {
        try {
            BASE64Encoder be = new BASE64Encoder();
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("sha-512");
            md.update(password.getBytes());
            return md.digest();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        }
        return null;
    }
```

And if i use this code to compare passwords it works perfectly

```
 if (encrypt(passwordField.getText()).compareTo(encrypt("password")) == 0 )
  system.out.print("true")
else *false
```

and i want to hide my password so i use console result of  `System.out.println(encrypt("Password"))` to compare so my code looks like this

```
    if (encrypt(passwordField.getText()).compareTo("5sg7KCrrLgIoRFlXIcwAu9pHyyRTfBd5+buE8EA54Wdua6hXPliNoQUlEOOqCjKp5Vh5riKwwtYh/n"+
"NvwKPoX4uw==") == 0 )
          system.out.print("true")
        else *false
```

it will always output false . i don't understand why.
Thank you for your time

Comment: First of all SHA-512 is a hash function which is not reversible. Encryption on the other hand is reversible.

Comment: How did you create "5sg7KCrrLgIoRFlXIcwAu9pHyyRTfBd5+buE8EA54Wdua6hXPliNoQUlEOOqCjKp5Vh5riKwwtYh/nNvwKPoX4uw=="? It doesn't have a valid Base64 length and is therefore longer than SHA-512 output.

Comment: You should never use a simple hash function to protect your user's passwords. You need to use a strong hashing scheme like PBKDF2, bcrypt, scrypt and Argon2. Be sure to use a high cost factor/iteration count. It is common to choose the cost so that a single iteration takes at least 100ms. See more: [How to securely hash passwords?](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/211/45523)

Comment: "5sg7KCrrLgIoRFlXIcwAu9pHyyRTfBd5+buE8EA54Wdua6hXPliNoQUlEOOqCjKp5Vh5riKwwtYh/nN‌​vwKPoX4uw==" I create this simply by using this line System.out.println(encrypt("Password"))  btw it is just some small program just for me. i am trying to learn

Comment: It has still an incorrect length. As a hint, it must be 88 characters when Base64-encoded. Also, try to take more care. The code you've presented in the last comment has a capital "P" whereas the code in the question has a lowercase "p".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read about hashing ...

In hashing if you try encoding a string say "hello" every time you will get different output although you are encoding the same string...

try the foll..

```
   for(i=1;i<10;i++)
   System.out.println(encrypt("password"));
```

You will get 9 diff results..but still they are comparable

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function